# Can you make a section of a table belong to a form using legal HTML?

Tags: html

I've tried entering the following in the [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options), but it failed to validate even when I used the "Validate HTML fragment" option:

```
<table>
  <form action="foo">
    <tr>
      <td>tables + forms = BOOM</td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

I think what I'm trying to do here is pretty clear, but the validator seems to be telling me this isn't allowed :(.

What if I want a single table to contain multiple forms? I guess there are alot of possibilities for how to split up a into several forms, but it seems reasonable to at least allow tr and/or tbody be children of form.

Using separate tables does not give the same effect, because the column widths may not end up being the same.

Comment: Why not use multiple tables? One per form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen, `<form>` elements can only appear entirely within a table cell (`<td>`), or entirely encapsulating a `<table>`. You're not going to be able to validate any other way; [the HTML DTDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html) all prohibit non-table elements as first-level child elements within `<table>` or `<tr>`.

That said, most browsers will understand what you're trying to do even if you don't validate.

Comment: In this case, browsers don't understand what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: The OP's original concern is about whether the markup validates: browsers happily accept non-validating HTML, including incorrectly nested tags.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, HTML4 specifies that you can't have a `<form>` directly inside a `<table>`, but you can have a form as a child of a `<td>`, maybe try this instead:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form action="foo">
        td + form = SUCCESS!
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(The is still true in HTML5 where a `<th>` may only contain [phrasing elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing), whereas `<form>` is classified as a [flow element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow).)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look e.g. [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xhtml-modularization-20010410/abstract_modules.html) at the list of what each type of element can contain.

Tables are fussy: they can contain only `caption?, ( col* | colgroup* ), (( thead?, tfoot?, tbody+ ) | ( tr+ ))`.

A form is 'block content' so you can put it anywhere that whose content can be 'Block', which includes anywhere whose content can be 'Flow', which includes inside table cells: so you can put a form inside a td.

Comment: thanks for the reference. Your third paragraph doesn't do much to de-obfuscate the spec though e.g. look at how many words you put in quotes.

Comment: @allyourcode I wasn't trying to explain the spec, I was trying to summarise it, or to mention/reference the relevent sections.